# Typescript: Classify objects by the attributes specified in them

Tags: arrays, typescript

[origin object array and expect object array ][1]
origin object array:
0:
amount: 100000000000000000000
feeTier: 0.3
price: 00000
priceDecimal: 0000
status: "unknown"
tokenXAddr: "0x*********"
tokenXSymbol: "USDC"
tokenYAddr: "0x**********"
tokenYSymbol: "aaa"
1: {orderId: '11', tokenXSymbol: 'USDC', tokenYSymbol: 'USDT', tokenXAddr: '0x**********', tokenYAddr: '0x**********', …}
2: {orderId: '4', tokenXSymbol: 'USDT', tokenYSymbol: 'USDC', tokenXAddr: '0x**********', tokenYAddr: '0x**********', …}

expect array:
0: {key: 'USDTUSDC0.3', data: Array(2), tokenXSymbol: 'USDT', tokenYSymbol: 'USDC', feeTier: 0.3}
1: {key: 'USDTUSDC0.05', data: Array(1), tokenXSymbol: 'USDT', tokenYSymbol: 'USDC', feeTier: 0.05}

I hope to reorganize an object array according to tokenxsymbol, tokenysymbol and feetier in the object array. The following is the method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, abcold. Consider formatting your post use a code block so others can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const resultList = useMemo(() => {
    return originList.reduce((acc: any, e: Order) => {
        const key = e.tokenXSymbol + e.tokenYSymbol + String(e.feeTier);
        const r = acc.find((e: any) => e.key === key);
        r
            ? r.data.push(e)
            : acc.push({
                  key,
                  data: [e],
                  tokenXSymbol: e.tokenXSymbol,
                  tokenYSymbol: e.tokenYSymbol,
                  feeTier: e.feeTier,
              });
        return acc;
    }, []);
}, [originList]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).